# Linker commands for SDL using MingW64

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, sdl, linker-errors

I am trying to run a simple Window program using SDL, unfortunately during linking, I get the error messages. I am using C++

```
skipping incompatible C:\Users\tinay\Desktop\dzivaguru\lib/libSDL2main.a when searching for -lSDL2main
x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible ...\lib\libSDL2main.a when searching for -lSDL2main
x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible ...\lib/libSDL2main.a when searching for -lSDL2main
mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lSDL2main: No such file or directory
```

The compile commands are via **task.json** in VS Code.

```json
      "type": "cppbuild",
      "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
      "command": "C:\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
      "args": [
        "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
        "-g",
        "-I${workspaceFolder}\\include",
        "-L${workspaceFolder}\\lib",
        "${workspaceFolder}\\src\\*.cpp",
        "-o",
        "${workspaceFolder}\\bin\\debug\\game.exe",
        "-lmingw32",
        "-lSDL2main",
        "-lSDL2",
        "-mwindows"
```

For some reason, I cannot access the **.a** files because it is saying they are incompatible.

I am looking for the adjustments to my compile commands to resolve this. The included links work well, and I can access and parse the code perfectly. It is only accessing these **.a** files that the compiler just refuses.

PS: This works well

```
#include "SDL/SDL2.h"
```

Comment: Did you download SDL or compile it yourself? That message usually means that you're compiling a 64-bit program and the libraries are 32-bit or vice versa.

Comment: No, I did not compile it. I downloaded it from their webpage. Is there a way to download the 32-bit version compiler or any flags in order to make the changes needed for compilation?

Comment: Are you using the files that came from the i686... directory or the ones from the x86_64... directory? Whichever it is, switch to the other one. I would assume the x86_64 files are the most appropriate.

Comment: The header and library file paths appear to be your working directory. Have you installed SDL in your project's working directory?

Comment: You have the wrong SDL binaries for your compiler. The official VSCode tutorial recommends using msys2 to install MinGW. Remove your current MinGW and follow the VSCode instructions: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw) then use pacman to install the correct MinGW binaries for your compiler: [https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-SDL2?repo=ucrt64](https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-SDL2?repo=ucrt64)

Comment: Looks like you are using 32-bit compiler with 64-bit libraries.

Comment: Thank you all for the help, the solution was to switch to the 64bit version found in the x86_64 files, and I also switched to the MSYS2 version of MinGW.

Thank you so much @RetiredNinja